# How do I initialize arrays of type string with one line of code?

Tags: c++, arrays, string, visual-c++, initialization

I declared an array of size 100 `string bin[100];` I want each array to be initialized as `""`. How do I initialize all of them with one line? I tried something like `bin[] = "";` and it doesn't work. Any help would be appreciated.

Default Constructor

```
RandomString()
{
    input = "";
    //bin[] = "";
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to do anything special, just `string bin[100];` is fine. The default constructor for `std::string` will be called for each element of the array.

If the array is a member of some class, initialize it in the member initialization list:

```
struct SomeClass
{
    std::string bin[100];
    SomeClass() : bin() // You can initialize arrays with () in the mem-init list
    {
    }
};
```

*Technically, the default constructor will be called even if you don't add `bin()` to the mem-init list, but it is good practice (as built-in types will be left uninitialized).

In C++, members of a class are initialized through initialization lists. For example, in the following examples, there is a difference in the code:

```
// First example
struct MyClass
{
    int i;
    SomeClass() : i(1)
    {
    }
};

// Second example
struct MyClass
{
    int i;
    SomeClass()
    {
        i = 1;
    }
};
```

In the first example, `i` is **initialized** to `1` in the initialization list. In the second example, `1` is **assigned** to `i`. You could think of the above code as doing the following:

```
int i = 1; // First example

int i; // Second example
i = 1;
```

For a built-in type like `int` there isn't much difference between the two, however the difference above can be very important in some situations, such as when the member is declared `const`:

```
struct SomeClass
{
    const int i;
    SomeClass()
    {
       i = 1; // Error!!
    }
};
```

In the above example, the const member **must** be initialized in the initialization list.

Comment: What would I put in my class constructor? Since i declared `string bin[100];`as my member function would I just leave the initialization blank in the class constructor?

Comment: I hope `bin` is a member variable and not a function. Initialize it in the member initialization list of the ctor, for example `MyClass::MyClass() : bin() {//body of ctor}`

Comment: oops, I meant to say member variable. And I'm not really understanding what you're saying about initializing it in the list of the ctor. How would I do that? I edited my first post to include how my constructor looks like.

Comment: @user2419691: It seems you are not familiar with initialization lists. They are the C++ way of initializing members of a class. See [this tutorial](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/101-constructor-initialization-lists/) for some more information. In your code example, it would look like this: `RandomString() : bin() { }`.

Comment: Ahh okay, I see what you mean now. Thank you for informing me about initialization lists. So putting `RandomString() : bin(){ }` basically initializes my array for all 100 of them, right?

Comment: Yes, that is what it does.

Comment: +1, just to note, the default constructor will anyway initialize string member to empty string even if not explicitly initialized.

Comment: @Sanish: Thanks for the comment, I updated the answer to clarify.

Comment: @JesseGood can you give an example where you pass an array into the constructor to be initialized in a data member? for example something like `someclass(std::string v[100]):bin(v);`. Because if bin is a vector `someclass(std::vector<std::string> i):bin(i){};` it compiles, but not with an array.

Comment: @AvraamMavridis: `someclass(std::string v[100])` is the same as `someclass(std::string* v)`. You cannot use the pointer to initialize the member array. The best you can do is a for loop or some other construct like `std::copy` to copy each element into the array.

Answer (score 0):

In your way, you just initialized the first element of the array, the default ctor initialize to null string. You want to initialize the 100 elements, just do the same thing for each of them.